How to (retroactively) apply markdown formatting?
I have an Apps Script function that fills in a presentation based on values entered in a Sheet. This script does not retain any sort of formatting, which is intended. I plan to use markdown notation with the values on the Sheet but Google Slides' built-in markdown does not work with this, as it is not retroactive.
Therefore, I want to write a script that goes through the text in a presentation, format every markdown wrapped text accordingly, and remove the markdown symbols.
When it comes to markdown, I mainly care about italic and bold text wrapped in single and double asterisk.
I already found a similar request for a Google Docs script which works, but I could not figure out a way to adapt that since Slides scripts handle text quite differently.
I could not find a way to access the text content of an entire presentation.
Here is my attempt at it, it doesn't return any errors but it does not do anything.
function slidesMarkdown() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();

  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var slide = slides[i];
    var shapes = slide.getShapes();

    for (var j = 0; j < shapes.length; j++) {
      var shape = shapes[j];

      if (shape.getText().length > 0) {
        var textElements = shape.getText();

        for (var k = 0; k < textElements.length; k++) {
          var textElement = textElements[k];
          var text = textElement.getText();

          if (text.startsWith("**") && text.endsWith("**")) {
            var boldText = text.substring(2, text.length - 2);
            textElement.setText(boldText);
            textElement.setBold(true);
          }

          if (text.startsWith("*") && text.endsWith("*")) {
            var italicText = text.substring(1, text.length - 1);
            textElement.setText(italicText);
            textElement.setItalic(true);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Your code might not be working because it's using startsWith and endsWith on the shape's text and it's very likely that you only have marked words inside the text.
One way  to improve your script is to use regular expresions.

Below there is a simple proposal.

Create a new presentation in Google Slides.

For the purposes of this question, please ensure that the automatic conversion of markdown in Google Slides is turned off.

Add your content and enclose shape text words / phrases between ** for bold and between * for italic.
Below there are a few examples:

Title slide, title shape: Hello **world**!
Title and body, body shape:
1. **Lorem** ipsum (first word bold)
2. Lorem **ipsum** (second word bold)
3. *Lorem* ipsum (first word italics)




Copy the below code


const PATTERN_BOLD = '\\*{2}[^*]+\\*{2}';
const PATTERN_ITALIC = '\\*[^*]+\\*';

function main(){
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slides = presentation.getSlides();
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
      ['applyBold_', 'applyItalic_'].forEach(fn => {
      this[fn](shape);
      })
    })
  })
}

/**
 * Applies bold style to text between **
 * @param {SlidesApp.Shape} shape
 */
function applyBold_(shape) 
{
  const matches = shape.getText().find(PATTERN_BOLD);
  matches.forEach(match => {
    match.replaceAllText('**','');
    match.getTextStyle().setBold(true);
    
  })
}

/**
 * Applies italic style to text between *
 * @param {SlidesApp.Shape} shape
 */
function applyItalic_(shape) {
  const matches = shape.getText().find(PATTERN_ITALIC);
  matches.forEach(match => {
    match.replaceAllText('*','');
    match.getTextStyle().setItalic(true);
    
  })
}


Click Extensions > Apps Script
Select the default content of Code.gs and paste the above code.
Click Run. The first time you will be required to authorize the script, please authorize it.
Go back to your presentation. The text marked for bold and italic should now have this style applied.

Key concepts
In Google Apps Script, to apply styles like bold and italic to specific words and phrases, we first have to retrieve an instance of Class TextRange for the specific word and phrases, then get an instance of Class TextStyle and use the methods SlidesApp.TextStyle.setBold(true)  and SlidesApp.TextStyle.setItalic(true), as shown in the above code.
SlidesApp.TextRange.find Patterns
Regarding the bold and italic patterns for SlidesApp.TextRange.find method in the above code, take them as simple examples. If you are looking for patterns that better fit your use case, see Regex: accurately match bold (**) and italics (*) item(s) from the input.
Resources

Editing and styling text

Related

Apps script to format selected text on a Google Slide
Format specific words in a Google Slide using App Script


Thank you! This is great! For ** wrapped text it tends to make it both bold and italic and removes only one set of asterisks. Thanks to the link you provided, I can work on some other notation that doesn't just use asterisks :) Maybe something like wrapping in  and . I appreciate the help!

@sabi I'm pretty sure that yesterday it was working fine. Anyway, I slightly changed the script: I replaced \*{2} and \* with ** and *, respectively, in replaceAllText.

If you still have problems, provide examples of shape text that help reproduce the behavior that you are seeing.
